# VBA part of two dimensional Array into combobox.List

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, combobox

in my code I get by SQL query two-dimensional array inside Variant queryResult.

```
queryResult = RetrieveRecordset("SELECT * FROM Materials;")
```

Array then looks like:

[image]

And if I try to fill up Combobox

```
cbSTPScrewedMaterial.List = queryResult
```

It fills only  values 1 and Plastic, but I wish to get values from Plastic to Hard Plastic -> queryResult(1) on image above, but when I type

```
cbSTPScrewedMaterial.List = queryResult(1)
```

VBA echoes me Runtime Error 9: Subscript out of range.
Do you have idea, what I'm doing wrong and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`queryResult` is a two-dimensional array with 2 rows and 5 columns

set your combobox `ColumnCount` property to `5`

```
cbSTPScrewedMaterial.ColumnCount = 5
```

and have them all shown

Furthermore `queryResult(1)` is trying to access a two-dimensional array as one-dimensional one, thus resulting in an error

you could use a function to return a one-dimensional array out of a given two-dimensional array row like follows

```
Option Explicit
Function GetQueryRow(arr As Variant, iRow As Long) As Variant
    Dim j As Long
    ReDim arrRow(LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)) As Variant

    For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        arrRow(j) = arr(iRow, j)
    Next j
    GetQueryRow = arrRow
End Function
```

to be used like:

```
Dim queryResult As Variant
Dim queryRow As Variant

queryResult = RetrieveRecordset("SELECT * FROM Materials;")
queryRow = GetQueryRow(queryResult, 1)
```

or "directly"

```
Dim queryRow As Variant

queryRow = GetQueryRow(RetrieveRecordset("SELECT * FROM Materials;"), 1)
```

or even "more directly"

```
MsgBox GetQueryRow(RetrieveRecordset("SELECT * FROM Materials;"), 1)(1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have seen rows as collumns and columns as rows, that was that problem. Thank you :-)